# How to create a table column where INT can't be less than 1 and more than 5?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried this code below but it didn't work

```
CREATE TABLE Groups
(
    GroupID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    GroupName NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    GroupRating INT NOT NULL,
    GroupYear  INT FROM 1 TO 5,
)
```

Comment: See table `CHECK` constraint and a `BETWEEN` expression: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: That feature is called "Check Constraint": https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: Could you share the documentation or article you obtained the `from 1 to 5` syntax from?

Comment: If your version is too old and does not support CHECK constraints (accepts but ignores) then use BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Groups
(
    GroupID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    GroupName NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    GroupRating INT NOT NULL,
    GroupYear  INT,
    CHECK CHK_Group (GroupYear>=1 AND GroupYear<=5)
)
```